# SQL Server intra-query parallelism deadlocks

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, database-deadlocks

We have a process that seeing some consistent intra-query parallelism desdlocks involving the following AD-HOC. I found the couple of work arounds available:

```
UPDATE VPG 
SET VPG.CountActual = COALESCE(PGI.CNT, 0) 
FROM ValidProductGroups AS VPG 
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT ProductGroupID, COUNT(ProductGroupID) AS 'CNT' 
     FROM ProdGroupItems WITH(NOLOCK)
     WHERE Deleted = 0 
     GROUP BY ProductGroupID) AS PGI ON PGI.ProductGroupID = VPG.ProductGroupID 
WHERE VPG.LocationID = 5
```

I added the non clustered index to the sub-query in the `Update` statement. Next step to add the `MAXDOP` query hint to the AD-HOC, but I'm bit confused to where I can add that in the update statement:

1. Is it at the end of the `Update` statement
2. or in the end of `SELECT` statement in the subquery?

Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

Query hints are not allowed in a subquery or CTE. You want to use query hint at the end of UPDATE statement.

```
UPDATE VPG 
SET VPG.CountActual = COALESCE(PGI.CNT, 0) 
FROM ValidProductGroups AS VPG 
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT ProductGroupID, COUNT(ProductGroupID) AS 'CNT' 
     FROM ProdGroupItems WITH(NOLOCK)
     WHERE Deleted = 0 
     GROUP BY ProductGroupID) AS PGI ON PGI.ProductGroupID = VPG.ProductGroupID 
WHERE VPG.LocationID = 5
OPTION (MAXDOP 1)
```

**More suggestions:**
You need a multi-pronged approach to eliminate (or reduce) Intra-query deadlocks. Before you go into query hints, I would suggest to optimize your index strategy.

I would suggest that you create a more appropriate index to support this query than the `IX_ProdGroupItems_ProductGroupID_ExtHierarchyID_ExtNodeID_1` index it currently relies on.

```
*wink* *wink*
```

Hope this helps,

_UB